# Name resolution in busybox

Tags: busybox, host-name-resolution

I have a statically linked busybox and want to be able to write `busybox telnet foo`. How do I specify the address of "foo"?

Do I really need `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and the corresponding dynamic libraries, or does busybox contain some own simple mechanism to consult `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: As Rui writes, this depends on the libc. What libc was this busybox compiled against? And with what configuration was busybox compiled? Also, how are you getting DNS? For example *wrt systems typically run dnsmasq and have a static host list that dnsmasq reads and serves via DNS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into my openWRT, I do not have any libnss* libraries installed. It seems that only libuClibc is used for that. libc.so.0 is a symlink to it.

```
root@RuiWifi:/lib# grep -ri hosts *
libc.so.0:/etc/hosts
libuClibc-0.9.33.2.so:/etc/hosts
```

> uClibc is an implementation of the standard C library that is much
>   smaller than glibc, which makes it useful for embedded systems.

If you are trying to put together a minimal environment, I would advise you to compile busybox against UClibc instead of glibc, and snooping around openWRT to see how they managed to put together such a distribution with such a small footprint.

[Compiling BusyBox with uClibc](http://www.finnie.org/2014/02/13/compiling-busybox-with-uclibc/)

Comment: In your case busybox seems to be dynamically linked. If I understand correctly uClibc looks directly at `/etc/hosts`, but my busybox seems not to care about the content of that file.

Comment: I assumed initially you were into one of the ...wrt systems, and then it just clicked me you only mentioned a *compiled*  busybox, hence my last paragraph and edit.

Answer (score 0):

See `dnsd` which can be built into Busybox:

```
root@alpine-linux [~]# ls -l $(which dnsd)
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root  root  12 Mar 17 23:12 /usr/sbin/dnsd -> /bin/busybox
```

[configuring dnsd](http://oao.no/wpe/2012/10/busybox-dns-server/)

I was also able configure `unbound` to provide name resolution for `.local` domains in Alpine Linux (which also uses Busybox).

See `local-data` in the [`unbound.conf` man page](https://unbound.net/documentation/unbound.conf.html). By default it is commented out of the config file.